# What is the probability that a uniformly random vector is spanned by a subset of basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Working in the set of Real Numbers.

Say that you're given a set of basis vectors $\{\mathbf{b}_i\}, \, i \in [n]$. Now, sample a vector **v** uniformly at random from the entire space. What is the probability that **v** can be written as a linear combination of any $n-1$ basis vectors? More specifically, is it finite or negligible?

Any references on how to go about this would be great too.

EDIT: The vector **v** has unit magnitude.

Comment: I presume the $n-1$ basis vector are fixed beforehand. In principle you should be a little bit more specific about what is your *uniform distribution* but if the distribution doesn't concentrate on discrete sets, then the probability is zero as it is a set of codimension one (and so has zero measure)

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is that sampling a vector uniformly at random from $\mathbb R^n$ isn't well-defined; you can't have a uniform distribution when your space is unbounded like this.

However, assuming any reasonably distribution, the probability is zero. The probability of your chosen vector being $0$ in the first coordinate is zero, as is the probability of being $0$ in the second coordinate, and so on. The probability of at least one of these happening is at most the sum of the probabilities of any of them happening, which is simply zero.

Comment: I'm not sure about your "isn't well-defined" part. Whether or not the random vector is spanned by some set of basis vectors is independent of the  random vector's magnitude. So you can equivalently just choose a random unit vector/direction on the Bloch sphere (unit sphere), whereby everything's bounded.

Comment: You're correct in saying that the question is "equivalent" to choosing it on the unit sphere, but the OP -- and i quote -- said "uniformly at random from the entire space". The first paragraph in my answer was just trying to address this misconception that such a random distribution exists.

Comment: Sorry I missed the part that they have unit magnitude.